# ClosedChannelException on FluentProducerTemplate with Apache Camel

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

I'm facing `ClosedChannelException` with my app, when I'm testing Apache Camel route.

```
rest().post("/{{camel.rest.version}}/ufx")
    .type(MyMsg.class)
    .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    .responseMessage().code(HttpStatus.SC_OK).responseModel(MyMsg.class).endResponseMessage()
    .responseMessage().code(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST).responseModel(MyMsg.class).endResponseMessage()
    .route().routeId("rst_myrest")      
    .to("direct:route_myroute")
    .endRest();

onException(ValidationException.class).
    handled(true).
    log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, LoggingConst.ERROR +" Validation exception: ${body}").
    onExceptionOccurred(validationExceptionProcessor).
    marshal().jaxb(MyMsg.class.getPackage().getName()).
    log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Error response ${body}").
    end();  

from("direct:route_myroute").routeId("rt_ufx")      
    .unmarshal().jaxb(MyMsg.class.getPackage().getName())
    .process("myvalidator")
    //some other lines
    .marshal().jaxb(MyMsg.class.getPackage().getName())
    .end();
```

In my test, invalid data is passed, so `ValidationExceptionProcessor` is invoked.

```
public class ValidationExceptionProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        ValidationException request = exchange.getException(ValidationException.class);
        MyMsg msg = new MyMsg();
        //preparing some pretty object
        exchange.getOut().setBody(msg);
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

It works fine when I'm invoking my app directly (from Postman, for example). Correct `MyMsg` object is logged and returned to user.
Junit-test `FluentProducerTemplate` is used to check the result:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@DirtiesContext
@Slf4j
@UseAdviceWith
public class myTest {

    @Produce(uri = "undertow:myaddress")
    FluentProducerTemplate holdProducer;

    @Test
    public void invalidDataException() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Exchange send = holdProducer.withHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethod.POST)
                .withHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
                .withBody(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/test/resources/Request.xml")))
                .send();
        Exception exception = send.getException(); //here I get java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-10-30T15:04:12.779+00:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper","stack_trace":"java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:122)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:596)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.flush(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:267)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.flush(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:162)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.flush(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:119)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.flushBlocking(Channels.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:612)
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.close(IOHelper.java:342)
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.close(IOHelper.java:406)
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.close(IOHelper.java:416)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.copyStream(DefaultHttpBinding.java:434)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteDirectResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:496)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:395)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.writeResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:322)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:209)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:73)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilte    rInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:211)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
","message":"Cannot close. Reason: null","camel.exchangeId":"ID-VRN26-1540911805592-0-3","camel.contextId":"","camel.breadcrumbId":"ID-VRN26-1540911805592-0-1","camel.messageId":"ID-VRN26-1540911805592-0-4"}
```

What is the difference between invoking from Fluent and a running app directly? How can it be fixed?

P.S.Changing message output to In() doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but not in the place I was looking for. Here is my Http code set:

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST is a Spring enum entry. And the result is a enum value:

```
BAD_REQUEST(400, "Bad Request"),
```

When my app was run inside Spring container, Spring did the enum-value unmarshal and I received a correct body with Http-400 code.

However with FluentProducerTemplate (with belongs to camel-libraries), no unmarshalling was done, and fluent crashes somewhere. (I do wonder where and why exactly. And why the error is so weird).

Switching to Camel header solved my problem

```
 exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
```

because Camel httpHeaders are not a enum, but a public-static-final field

```
public static final int SC_BAD_REQUEST = 400;
```

it also works fine if you call .value() for Spring enum

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
```